# VB6 to C#: IUnknown

Tags: c#, properties, vb6, vb6-migration, iunknown

I have a property in VB6 that I am trying to convert to C#. It is as follows:

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    'this property allows you to enumerate
    'this collection with the For...Each syntax
    Set NewEnum = m_coll.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

`m_coll` is private variable that is now an `ArrayList` instead of the former `Collection`.

`m_coll`is being populated with one of my own class objects. This property is of the type **IUnknown** as you can see.

I may just not be thinking properly at this point, but is there an equivalent to this sort of property in C#?

Comment: Are you thinking of IEnumerable? That allows you to use a foreach statement on a collection.

Comment: You should not be using `ArrayList`.  Use the generic `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to do a foreach over a class (like you could by exposing NewEnum() as IUnknown in vb6) you can have your class implement IEnumerable - e.g.:

```
   public class MyClass : IEnumerable 
    {
        private List<string> items = new List<string>();

        public MyClass()
        {
            items.Add("first");
            items.Add("second");
        }


        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return items.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

which would allow you to use it like this:

```
  MyClass myClass =new MyClass();
            foreach (var itm in myClass)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(itm);
            }
```

I've used `List<string>` for simplicity, but you can use `List<yourCustomClass>`

Comment: You answered after I already figured it out, but I will still give you the point ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry I wasn't quicker  :)